# How to fix Django South issue with regards to localflavor in Django 1.5?

Tags: django, django-south, django-localflavor

I'm starting a new project and I'm using Django 1.5. I found out that the localflavor stuff has been removed from Django 1.5 and is now a separate installable package. So I installed it. In my models.py I'm importing the U.S. localflavors to get my states:

```
from django_localflavor_us.models import USStateField
```

In my model, I have this field:

```
state = USStateField(default='VA')
```

When I attempt to run a migration with South, I get the following message now:

! Cannot freeze field 'playerstats.location.state'
 ! (this field has class django_localflavor_us.models.USStateField)

! South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom
 ! fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the
 ! models parser (it often broke things).
 ! To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork

I read through the wiki article, but I find it very verbose and complex. My USStateField isn't considered a custom field now in 1.5 is it? Has anyone else run into this issue in 1.5? And how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried adding the introspection rule?

```
add_introspection_rules([], ["^django_localflavor_us\.models\.USStateField"])
```

Answer (score 12):

As of django-localflavor version 1.0, simply adding "localflavor" to your `INSTALLED_APPS` is all you need to get South to properly pick it up.  https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?highlight=south#installation

Answer (score 2):

I had to tweak Hedde van der Heide's solution to get mine to work. It looks like this:

`add_introspection_rules([], ["^localflavor\.us\.models\.USStateField"])`